# CHECKDB never completes, hanging due to wait_type RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a scheduled database maintenance task that was reported to be taking longer and longer to complete until finally it stopped completing altogether. The task runs a CHECKDB against a specific database.

When I run `select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where (status = 'suspended')` I see the suspended `DBCC TABLE CHECK` command. Taking its `session_id` and comparing it to the results of `select * from sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants` I see that the memory grant has a `requested_memory_kb` of 1515704kb (1.515GB). `required_memory_kb` is only 512kb. `resource_semaphore_id` is 0.

If I run `select * from sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores` I see that the `resource_sempahore_id` 0 has a `target_memory_kb` of 1174200kb, `max_target_memory_kb` of 6063000kb, a `total_memory_kb` of 1174200kb, and an `available_memory_kb` of 1174200kb.

It looks like my CHECKDB is failing because its waiting task is requesting 1.5GB of memory grant, but the resource semaphore will never be capable of granting that memory because it's entire available memory pool is only 1.17GB. Despite showing its `max_target_memory_kb` at 6063000kb (6GB) it never grows beyond its current target, even with a task waiting due to insufficient memory.

I'm trying to determine:

1. What is causing my CHECKDB task to request 1.5GB of memory grant, when the `required_memory_kb` is only 512kb. Why is the requested amount 2950 times higher than the required amount.
2. Why is a task requesting more memory than the SQL server has available in total in its resource semaphore to grant? (1.5GB requested vs 1.15GB available)
3. Is there anything I can do to resolve this without simply adding more RAM to my SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

"Required Memory" is a little misleading. [This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2827/troubleshooting-sql-server-resourcesemaphore-waittype-memory-issues/) does a good job of explaining required vs requested memory. In short, required memory is just how much would be required to perform the necessary hash joins and sorts in memory. The remainder of the requested memory is for actual rows.

You could potentially do `DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY`, which checks the consistency of pages, etc, but will not verify row-level data. Otherwise, there's definitely a memory bottleneck there.